# Plotting data and doing a least squares regression with cosines in java

Tags: java, plot, least-squares

I have data I would like to plot, and more importantly, do a least squares regression on using cosines (instead of using polynomials):

[image: http://imgur.com/AkEaE.png]

Any recommendations? Thanks.

Comment: What is the algebraic form of your cosine regression?

Comment: Are you looking for packages to use, or Java2D advice, or how to do a least squares regression?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the following page solves the regression part of your aim:

http://www.teneighty.org/software/index.html?f=fft&c=e98b8

Answer (score 0):

You might find this demo [Least Squares & Data Fitting](http://mste.illinois.edu/users/exner/java.f/leastsquares/) helpful since it solves a few of your problems.

Comment: I've used that. Unfortunately, that is a regression that uses polynomials. I need one that uses cosines, fitting to this equation: http://imgur.com/AkEaE.png

Answer (score 0):

Just a bit of cautionary advice.  Using a Fourier series makes sense if you think your underlying function has a cosine series as a basis; however, if you are using it as a basis for an arbitrary function (with unknown shape), you may do better trying to guess at a more specific underlying function type (polynomial, exponential, etc).

I did some constrained optimization on such a series, and the function wiggled around so much it was hard to say if my fit was meaningfull; my fit function had great number of local maxima.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. We're pretty sure the underlying function has a cosine series as a basis though.

Answer (score 0):

[MathGL](http://mathgl.sourceforge.net/) can plot, fit (by help of GSL) and show fitting result - see [this sample](http://mathgl.sourceforge.net/mathgl_en/mathgl_en_96.html#Fitting-sample)